# Heroku vs Own Linux Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, hosting

I know many rails developer praise heroku but they're very expensive imo. 1 Dyno is about $36 and that does not include the addons. My question is how hard is it to manage your own server, like what are the problems you would have to look out for.

**My experience**

I've setup my own server on a rackspace cloud that included ubuntu 10.10, apache, passenger, mysql, rails and need gems for the application. I am not a system administrator but I am familiar with linux and some commands. Though I setup my own server and deployed my app what are the reasons for me to use heroku rather then setting up and deploying and using my own server?

Comment: that depends, do you really demand the scalability and one-key deploy?

Answer (score 4):

The advantage is heroku is set up for rails deploys with a minimum amount of effort. If the cost:convenience is in your favor, then you deploy to heroku.

If you have the know-how and can administer your own server, then you do it yourself and save money.

Heroku can also be completely free for a low traffic site, so it can be useful for deploying a development build to for a client meeting or walkthrough

To put it another way, what's the advantage of buying, preparing and grilling steak versus eating at a restaurant?